# Gradle sync lock

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

> Gradle sync failed: Could not create parent directory for lock file
>   C:\Program Files\Android\Android
>   Studio\gradle\gradle-4.10.1\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.10.1-all\455itskqi2qtf0v2sja68alqd\gradle-4.10.1-all.zip.lck

I don't know what to do. I need some help.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

delete gradle folder from your machine an dtry. in my setup it is 'C:\Users\xyz.gradle'.

Comment: Thank you.I'll try that one.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could understand, there might be many possible reasons for that. If you are using windows, then try running your Android Studio as Run as Administrator.

Another reason could be the offline work is enabled in your Android Studio (I suppose there is no problem with your internet connection). You might consider unchecking the offline work checkbox if it is already checked. You will find the offline work checkbox in the `Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle`.

Hope that helps.